# Changing a CNAME entry for AWS Global accelerator

Tags: amazon-web-services, auth0, amazon-route53, aws-global-accelerator

I'm trying to register a custom domain with Auth0 handling user authentication.  To prove ownership for the certificates, I need to change the CNAME entry to add their content string.  However, I would also like to run my site behind AWS Global Accelerator.

Global Accelerator appears to automatically create a CNAME entry for the subdomain and I'm not sure how to change it.  This setup is kind of complicated, I'm not sure how to set it up.

How do I preserve Global Accelerator function but also implement third-party authentication?